# Algorithm to define a 2d grid

Tags: optimization, inversion

Suppose a grid is defined by a set of grid parameters: its origin (x0, y0), an angel [image: \theta] between one side and x axis, and increments [image: \Delta{p}] and [image: \Delta{q}] - please see the figure below.

[image: A grid with scattered points]

There are scattered points with known coordinates on the grid but they don’t exactly fall on grid intersections. Is there an algorithm to find a set of grid parameters to define the grid so that the points are best fit to grid intersections?

Suppose the known coordinates are:
(2    , 5.464), (3.732, 6.464), (5.464, 7.464)
(3    , 3.732), (4.732, 4.732), (6.464, 5.732)
(4    , 2    ), (5.732, 3    ), (7.464, 4    ).
I expect the algorithm to find the origin (4, 2), the angle 30 degree, and the increments both 2.

Comment: I assume the scattered points are approximately arranged as a grid, otherwise your question does not make sense to me. If so, how is „best fit“ defined? Is it e.g. the minimum sum of distances of a point to its nearest neighbor?

Comment: @Reinhard Männer Your assumption is correct. Here "best fit" could be minimum sum of distances of a point to its nearest grid intersection, or minimum sum of distance squares. Usually solutions to least squares problems are easier, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem by finding a matrix that transforms points from positions (0, 0), (0, 1), ... (2, 2) onto the given points.

Although the grid has only 5 degrees of freedom (position of the origin + angle + scale), it is easier to define the transformation using 2x3 matrix A, because the problem can be made linear in this case.

Let a point with index (x0, y0) to be transformed into point (x0', y0') on the grid, for example (0, 0) -> (2, 5.464) and let a_ij be coefficients of matrix A. Then this pair of points results in 2 equations:

```
a_00 * x0 + a_01 * y0 + a_02 = x0'
a_10 * x0 + a_11 * y0 + a_12 = y0'
```

The unknowns are a_ij, so these equations can be written in form

```
a_00 * x0 + a_01 * y0 + a_02 + a_10 * 0 + a_11 * 0 + a_12 * 0 = x0'
a_00 * 0 + a_01 * 0 + a_02 * 0 + a_10 * x0 + a_11 * y0 + a_12 = y0'
```

or in matrix form

```
K0 * (a_00, a_01, a_02, a_10, a_11, a_12)^T = (x0', y0')^T
```

where

```
K0 = (
    x0, y0, 1,  0,  0,  0
    0,  0,  0,  x0, y0, 1
)
```

These equations for each pair of points can be combined in a single equation

```
K * (a_00, a_01, a_02, a_10, a_11, a_12)^T = (x0', y0', x1', y1', ..., xn', yn')^T
```

or `K * a = b`
where

```
K = (
    x0, y0, 1,  0,  0,  0
    0,  0,  0,  x0, y0, 1
    x1, y1, 1,  0,  0,  0
    0,  0,  0,  x1, y1, 1
    ...
    xn, yn, 1,  0,  0,  0
    0,  0,  0,  xn, yn, 1
)
```

and `(xi, yi), (xi', yi')` are pairs of corresponding points

This can be solved as a non-homogeneous system of linear equations. In this case the solution will minimize sum of squares of distances from each point to nearest grid intersection. This transform can be also considered to maximize overall likelihood given the assumption that points are shifted from grid intersections with normally distributed noise.

```
a = (K^T * K)^-1 * K^T * b
```

This algorithm can be easily implemented if there is a linear algebra library is available. Below is an example in Python:

```py
import numpy as np

n_points = 9
aligned_points = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
grid_points = [(2, 5.464), (3.732, 6.464), (5.464, 7.464), (3, 3.732), (4.732, 4.732), (6.464, 5.732), (4, 2), (5.732, 3), (7.464, 4)]

K = np.zeros((n_points * 2, 6))
b = np.zeros(n_points * 2)
for i in range(n_points):
    K[i * 2, 0] = aligned_points[i, 0]
    K[i * 2, 1] = aligned_points[i, 1]
    K[i * 2, 2] = 1
    K[i * 2 + 1, 3] = aligned_points[i, 0]
    K[i * 2 + 1, 4] = aligned_points[i, 1]
    K[i * 2 + 1, 5] = 1
    
    b[i * 2] = grid_points[i, 0]
    b[i * 2 + 1] = grid_points[i, 1]
    
# operator '@' is matrix multiplication
a = np.linalg.inv(np.transpose(K) @ K) @ np.transpose(K) @ b
A = a.reshape(2, 3)
print(A)
```

```
[[ 1.     1.732  2.   ]
 [-1.732  1.     5.464]]
```

Then the parameters can be extracted from this matrix:

```
theta = math.degrees(math.atan2(A[1, 0], A[0, 0]))
scale_x = math.sqrt(A[1, 0] ** 2 + A[0, 0] ** 2)
scale_y = math.sqrt(A[1, 1] ** 2 + A[0, 1] ** 2)
origin_x = A[0, 2]
origin_y = A[1, 2]
```

```
theta = -59.99927221917264
scale_x = 1.99995599951599
scale_y = 1.9999559995159895
origin_x = 1.9999999999999993
origin_y = 5.464
```

However there remains a minor issue: matrix A corresponds to an affine transform. This means that grid axes are not guaranteed to be perpendicular. If this is a problem, then the first two columns of the matrix can be modified in a such way that the transform preserves angles.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. The idea of making the problem linear by using the 2X3 matrix is briliant. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you possibly give more details on preserving angles? What I can think of is the rotation matrix: the coefficients, a_00, a_01, a_10, and a_11, compose a rotation matrix, and we have a_00 = a_11, a_10 = -a01, and a_00 * a_00 + a_01 * a_01 = 1. However, the last one will make the system non-linear. Thanks again.

Comment: Constraining the angles happened out to be much trickier than I though. You are right about the constraint that should be added. I had an idea of transforming the coefficients in such way that this constraint becomes constrain on norm of coefficients, making it [Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem), but it seem to require complex numbers. Another option is to use different approach, requiring singular value decomposition https://math.stackexchange.com/a/225423/175570 , which works perfectly for similarity transforms, but doesn't account for scaling

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I fixed the mistakes and resolved sign ambiguities, so now this algorithm produces the expected result. However it should be tested to see if all cases are handled correctly.

Here is another attempt to solve this problem. The idea is to decompose transformation into non-uniform scaling matrix and rotation matrix `A = R * S` and then solve for coefficients `sx, sy, r1, r2` of these matrices given restriction that `r1^2 + r2^2 = 1`. The minimization problem is described here: [How to find a transformation (non-uniform scaling and similarity) that maps one set of points to another?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955634/how-to-find-a-transformation-non-uniform-scaling-and-similarity-that-maps-one)

```py
def shift_points(points):
    n_points = len(points)
    shift = tuple(sum(coords) / n_points for coords in zip(*points))
    shifted_points = [(point[0] - shift[0], point[1] - shift[1]) for point in points]
    return shifted_points, shift

n_points = 9
aligned_points = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
grid_points = [(2, 5.464), (3.732, 6.464), (5.464, 7.464), (3, 3.732), (4.732, 4.732), (6.464, 5.732), (4, 2), (5.732, 3), (7.464, 4)]

aligned_points, aligned_shift = shift_points(aligned_points)
grid_points, grid_shift = shift_points(grid_points)
c1, c2 = 0, 0
b11, b12, b21, b22 = 0, 0, 0, 0
for i in range(n_points):
    c1 += aligned_points[i][0] ** 2
    c2 += aligned_points[i][0] ** 2
    b11 -= 2 * aligned_points[i][0] * grid_points[i][0]
    b12 -= 2 * aligned_points[i][1] * grid_points[i][0]
    b21 -= 2 * aligned_points[i][0] * grid_points[i][1]
    b22 -= 2 * aligned_points[i][1] * grid_points[i][1]
k = (b11 ** 2 * c2 + b22 ** 2 * c1 - b21 ** 2 * c2 - b12 ** 2 * c1) / \
    (b21 * b11 * c2 - b12 * b22 * c1)
# r1_sqr and r2_sqr might need to be swapped
r1_sqr = 2 / (k ** 2 + 4 + k * math.sqrt(k ** 2 + 4))
r2_sqr = 2 / (k ** 2 + 4 - k * math.sqrt(k ** 2 + 4))
for sign1, sign2 in [(1, 1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, -1)]:
    r1 = sign1 * math.sqrt(r1_sqr)
    r2 = sign2 * math.sqrt(r2_sqr)
    scale_x = -b11 / (2 * c1) * r1 - b21 / (2 * c1) * r2
    scale_y = b12 / (2 * c2) * r2 - b22 / (2 * c2) * r1
    if scale_x >= 0 and scale_y >= 0:
        break
theta = math.degrees(math.atan2(r2, r1))
```

There might be ambiguities in choosing `r1_sqr` and `r2_sqr`. Origin point can be estimated from `aligned_shift` and `grid_shift`, but I didn't implement it yet.

```
theta = -59.99927221917264
scale_x = 1.9999559995159895
scale_y = 1.9999559995159895
```

Comment: It seems that you have figured out the solution to the minimizing problem in the linked post for N=2. I can see here c1 and c2 are for C transpose in the linked post, and b_ij are for B transpose. However, I am confused by your expressions for k, r1_sqr, and r2_sqr, etc. Could you possibly give some explanation on those? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the linked post by writing out the solution, as there is not convenient way to write formulas using LaTeX here.